# Masonry - Expanded box on document ready

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to set the first box to an expanded state when document is ready in Masonry?

http://jsfiddle.net/vDGTC/

Also would be great to know how to animate certain boxes up, as opposed to down which seems to be the default. I need to apply this to the bottom row of boxes so the total dims - or layout container -  of all boxes remains constant regardless of what is expanded.

Many thanks, this is one hell of a plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to the bottom of your script:

```
$('.expandable:first').click();
```

After you set everything we're basically just executing a click event on the first element.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/xHvvT/1/

Comment: Elegant solution. Thanks v much.

Comment: Any ideas on how to animate some boxes to slide up instead of down?

Comment: To clarify my question, I need to make the boxes in the bottom row slide UP thus taking up the space of the box directly above it. The boxes are then rearranged around it.

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for but I'm not certain how to accomplish this. The best I could do is have the boxes on the bottom row to animate up but the rearranging doesn't rearrange the items around it in the first and second row. Masonry animates it back down to the 2nd row. http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/TXaVZ/2/